# How do I add appSettings from C# code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, application-settings

How do I add values to the app.config or web.config's `appSettings` section in C#?

Comment: @spender It was hard to tell; about 86% of the words written had nothing to do with what the OP actually wanted.

Comment: That's for sure. Looking for a dupe.

Comment: I marked as a dupe... although target question specifically mentions winforms, it's also good for WPF. Feel free to retag/edit this question if I've missed the mark.